# Stripper won’t take off paint and now sander is gumming

Tags: paint, furniture, table

I started refinishing an old table with red paint.
Years ago my mom used paint stripper to get rid of the paint but there was still a lot left.
I used several rounds of paint stripper with a scrapper and steel wool but the wood is still stained red (at best, some areas still have paint).
After wiping and letting it dry I thought I would sand down til there was no more red. I can’t go 30 seconds without the sander gumming up.
Any advise on getting the wood in any condition to paint or stain is appreciated.

Comment: Pictures might help. But it sounds to me (I am **not** a woodworking expert) like the paint soaked very deep into the wood. Depending on the type and thickness of the wood, it might be better to prime and paint - i.e., cover it up - rather than strip and stain/finish. If you don't get good answers here, you may want to try [Woodworking StackExchange](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/) but if you do that then you should delete this question as having the same question in two places is not recommended.

Comment: No need to delete your question, just because some do not know the answer.

Comment: Have you tried wet sanding?  If your substrate material can handle some dampness, that will help keep you from gumming up.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that you try a heat gun for removing the old paint. They work well on thick old layers of gummy paint.

You say you need

> "advise on getting the wood in any condition to paint or stain"

Advice on repainting, as opposed to staining, would be different.

To paint, it is generally not necessary to entirely remove the existing finish. You would only need to remove any *unsound* areas of the existing finish, and de-gloss (make dull and smooth) the rest of the surface.

To stain, you would need to strip all existing paint and then sand until you have clean, smooth, raw wood (or as clean and smooth as is acceptable to you).

Answer (score 0):

There is a product for that.

If you are trying to remove large amount of paint use the mesh sand disk

Example here [Mesh sanding](https://www.acmetools.com/dewalt-9in-sanding-mesh-150x-5pk-dwam1505p/885911694650.html?msclkid=cc034116181e1ae1516427142a173aff&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Shopping-National-Search%20Only-Profit%20Margin%20Target-33-35&utm_term=4579328496297570&utm_content=Profit%20Margin%2033%25%20-%2035%25)